# How to remove a item/index from a FlatList in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a data which is rendered as view and came across a issue on how to remove that particular index which is swiped

I have used FlatList as follows

```
render() {
this.leftOpenValue =  Dimensions.get('window').width;
this.rightOpenValue = -Dimensions.get('window').width;

return (   

     <FlatList 
            data = {data}  
            keyExtractor = {data => data.id}                
            renderItem={ ({item}) => (

                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <SwipeView            
                        disableSwipeToRight = {false}
                        renderVisibleContent={() => 
                            <View>
                                <Text style={styles.text}> {item.title} </Text>     // This repeats 9 times (9 Index)              
                            </View>          
                        }
                        renderRightView={() => (
                            <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent: 'flex-end', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: 'red'}}>

                            </View>
                        )}

                        leftOpenValue = {this.leftOpenValue}
                        rightOpenValue = {this.rightOpenValue}
                        onSwipedLeft={() => alert("deleted")}
                        swipeDuration = {300}
                        swipeToOpenPercent = {40}
                        disableSwipeToRight = {true}
                    />
                </View>  

            )}
    />
);
```

I have used Swipeview to swipe (react-native-swipeview) and delete the index in flatlist

I have an issue on how to remove an item from flatList

Comment: What code have you written to try and remove the item for your list/data?  General pattern is to pass a uniquely identifiable id (key, index, etc..) to your delete item callback and filter your data on values that *don't* equal that key. This returns a new array without that entry and you want to store that back into your state.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

General pattern is to pass a uniquely identifiable `id` (key, index, etc...) to your delete handler and filter your data on values that don't equal that key. This returns a new array without that entry to store in state.

```
deleteItemById = id => {
  const filteredData = this.state.data.filter(item => item.id !== id);
  this.setState({ data: filteredData });
}

render() {
  ...

  return (   
    <FlatList 
      data={data} // Assuming this is `this.state.data`
      keyExtractor={({item}) => item.id}                
      renderItem={({item}) => (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <SwipeView
            ...
            onSwipedLeft={() => this.deleteItemById(item.id)}
            ...
          />
        </View>  
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

Using a curried handler. This saves using an anonymous callback by setting the callback to be an event handler with the `id` enclosed in the function scope.

```
deleteItemById = id => () => {
  const filteredData = this.state.data.filter(item => item.id !== id);
  this.setState({ data: filteredData });
}

render() {
  ...

  return (   
    <FlatList 
      data={data} // Assuming this is `this.state.data`
      keyExtractor={({item}) => item.id}                
      renderItem={({item}) => (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <SwipeView
            ...
            onSwipedLeft={this.deleteItemById(item.id)}
            ...
          />
        </View>  
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Is there a faster alternative to using .filter() to sort through the entire list until we find the item to delete?

Comment: @iamfrank You could pass an index instead and slice it out, but since you still need to return a new array (with the other elements) the time complexity is still the same, i.e. deleting an element from an array **and** returning a new array reference is an **O(n)** operation. Above we're not really using filter to "find" the element, we're using it primarily for the purpose of returning a new array.

Comment: @famfamfam I don't quite understand your comment. Is that a question? If it isn't just a trivial issue it might be better to ask a new question on stackoverflow regarding any specific question/issue you have. You can reference this answer if it is something you are working with or trying to implement. Feel free to ping (@ me) in a comment here with a link to your post, and I can take a look when available.

Comment: in this method, images get re drawn on flat list as there position is changed after removing a item. Is there better way to remove item so that images do not get re appear on list rather simple move to new position.

Comment: @CrackerKSR It's unclear (*to me*) what exactly you mean by "images get re drawn on flat list as there position is changed after removing a item"? Can you clarify? Also, is your question related removing an item from the array, or is it more about a rendering issue of some child component/element/etc? In either case it may be better to ask a new question on SO. If you do, feel free to ping me here in a comment with a link to the question and I can take a look at my earliest convenience.

Answer (score 3):

Pass an Id of the item to `onSwipeLeft={this.deleteItem(item.id)}` and update the data using setState.

```
state = {
    data: [{
      title: 'Hello world',
      id: 'hello'
    },{
      title: 'World says hello',
      id: 'say'
    }]
}

deleteItem = (id) => {

   this.setState({
    data: this.state.data.filter(item => item.id !== id)
   })

}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, it's work well for me, 
I have another case that makes a problem can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63744329/cant-update-the-state-after-pull-to-get-new-data) question, please?

Comment: by this method the image items after the target item (to delete) gets re-drawn on the flatlist. is there better way to avoid this issue

Answer (score 0):

Do a normal object deletion then filter your state to clean it

```
 let _rem = this.state.data;
 delete  _rem[index_no];
 this.setState({data: this.state.data.filter(args=>args!==index_no)});
```