# React Native FlatList Delete Item

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to delete item from the FlatList. However, the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53855424/how-to-remove-a-item-index-from-a-flatlist-in-react-native) is not working for my code. When I run my code, I am getting error such as '*index is not defined*'.

I have yet to find other post regarding this issue so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Code snippet provided below:**

```
   export default class FrCreateScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            //new timeSlots
            timeSlots: [],
        }
    }

    setEndTime = (event, appointmentEndTime, textEndTime) => {
        appointmentEndTime = appointmentEndTime || this.state.appointmentEndTime;
        textEndTime = textEndTime || moment(appointmentEndTime).format('h:mm a').toString();
        this.setState({
            showEndTime: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? true : false,
            appointmentEndTime,
            textEndTime,

            timeSlots: [
                ...this.state.timeSlots,
                {
                    apptdate: this.state.textAppointmentDate,
                    appttime: this.state.textAppointmentTime,
                    endTime: textEndTime,
                }
            ],
        });
    }

    deleteDateTime = (id) => {
        const filteredData = this.state.timeSlots.filter(item => item.id !== id);
        this.setState({ timeSlots: filteredData });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                ...
                <View>
                    <FlatList
                        data={this.state.timeSlots}
                        keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => index.toString()}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => {
                            return (
                                <View style={styles.containerList}>
                                    ...
                                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.deleteDateTime(index)}>
                                            <Feather name="trash" style={styles.icon} />
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            );
                        }}
                    />
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        )
    };
};
```

**Screenshot below:**

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok fixed. on touchable onPress, the argument should be '`item.index`' instead of '`index`'.

here's the correct code:

```
renderItem={({ item,index }) => {
                            return (
                                <View style={styles.containerList}>
                                    ...
                                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.deleteDateTime(item.index)}>
                                            <Feather name="trash" style={styles.icon} />
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            );
                        }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add index inside renderItem `{ item, index }`

```
renderItem = {({ item, index }) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.containerList}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.deleteDateTime(index)}>
                <Feather name="trash" style={styles.icon} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried adding `index` inside renderItem, and it solved the error issue. However, it fails to delete the item.

Answer (score 0):

While rendering in map function , it provides the index too, so try adding that.

```
renderItem={({ item,index }) => {
                            return (
                                <View style={styles.containerList}>
                                    ...
                                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.deleteDateTime(index)}>
                                            <Feather name="trash" style={styles.icon} />
                                        </TouchableOpacity>
                                    </View>
                                </View>
                            );
                        }}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi, I tried adding `index` inside renderItem, and it solved the error issue. However, it fails to delete the item.