# How do I move flatlist items in one screen to another screen in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

I am trying to transfer todo list items in a flatlist, from one screen to another screen. Specifically, when the user clicks the trash can, I want the items to be transferred from the Home Screen (Todo Now) to the Completed Screen.

Home Screen (Todo Now) code:

```
export default function Home({ navigation }) {
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const [reviews, setReviews] = useState([
    {
      title: "Update old projects",
      rating: 2,
      body: "lorem ipsum",
      key: "1",
    },
    {
      title: "Fix React DevTools",
      rating: 5,
      body: "lorem ipsum",
      key: "2",
    },
    {
      title: "Download Yarn",
      rating: 4,
      body: "lorem ipsum",
      key: "3",
    },
  ]);

  const addReview = (review) => {
    review.key = Math.random().toString();
    setReviews((currentReviews) => {
      return [review, ...currentReviews];
    });
    setModalOpen(false);
  };

  const pressHandler = (key) => {
    setReviews((prevReviews) => {
      return prevReviews.filter((review) => review.key != key);
    });
      };

...
<FlatList
        data={reviews}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Card>
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <Text
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ReviewDetails", item)}
                style={globalStyles.titleText}
              >
                {item.title}
              </Text>
              <MaterialIcons
                onPress={() => pressHandler(item.key)}
                name="delete"
                style={styles.check}
                size={18}
                color={"#333"}
              />
            </View>
          </Card>
        )}
      />
```

Completed Screen flatlist code:

```
<FlatList
        data={reviews}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("ReviewDetails", item)}
          >
            <Card>
              <Text style={globalStyles.titleText}>{item.title}</Text>
            </Card>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
```

What modifications do I need to make to move be able to move the todo items from the Home Screen (Todo Now) to the Completed Screen (ideally after clicking on a todo item)?

[image: Home Screen (Todo Now)]
[image: Completed Screen]

Comment: helloo, where is your flatlist ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53855424/how-to-remove-a-item-index-from-a-flatlist-in-react-native

Comment: @AmirDoreh I added the code pertaining to the flatlists. Thanks so much.

Comment: Rather than having everything in local state move the array to context then you can update the item status and show items according to the status

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan Do you mean the React Context API?

Comment: @snuffydoug yes, currently you are storing everything in your component state, if you move it to a common place it will be easy

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan Solid advice. Thanks Guru.